# Getting the information about the currently playing video

Tags: android, video

Newbie in Android.

I have an application, I want to show some information about currently playing video. Video could be opened in any different application. No matter what (browser or any custom app). All I need to know is: title, length, current position. Is it possible?

Any advices or directions are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible?

No. There is no requirement for apps to tell other apps what they are doing. This includes video apps telling other apps what videos are playing.

Comment: Thank you. I was also thinking about something like casting alternative. You add Cast support to your app, then you able to press cast button and share a video to the Google Home which has an access to it.